# Abelian sandpile

Tags: performance, array, vb.net, integer

I am trying to programm the [Abelian sandpile model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_sandpile_model) in VisualBasic. Also, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MtEUErz7Gg) is a youtube video made by Numberphile about the very same topic.

Here is a picture (\$2^{20}\$ grains of sand) I made with my programm:

[image: 1048576 grains of and dropped.]

The current version workes fine - for now.

However, with large amounts of sand the calculation takes a very long time, and I wonder: Is there a possibility of speeding the code up?

To be fair, I am mostly self-taught in VB, so my code is likely to be ugly.

I'd be happy if you could take a look at my code and tell me, where I can make improvements. Thanks!

### Variables - Deklaration

```
Dim WDTH As Integer = 1000
Dim HGHT As Integer = 1000
Dim Array1(WDTH, HGHT) As Integer
Dim Done As Boolean
Dim Temp1 As Integer = 0
Dim Temp2 As Integer = 0
```

### Calculation

The first thing I do is resetting the array to 0.

```
For y As Integer = 0 To HGHT
    For x As Integer = 0 To WDTH
        Array1(x, y) = 0
    Next
Next
```

The sand is placed on the grid:

```
Array1(500, 500) = 2 ^ 20
```

Then the calculation happens:

```
    Done = False
    Do
        Done = True
        For y As Integer = 0 To HGHT
            For x As Integer = 0 To WDTH
                If Array1(x, y) >= 4 Then
                    Done = False
                    Temp1 = Array1(x, y) Mod 4
                    Temp2 = (Array1(x, y) - Temp1) / 4
                    Array1(x, y) = Temp1
                    Array1(x + 1, y) += Temp2
                    Array1(x - 1, y) += Temp2
                    Array1(x, y + 1) += Temp2
                    Array1(x, y - 1) += Temp2
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Loop Until Done = True
```

This describes the toppling of the sand. I go through the entire array, check if a sandpile needs to topple, I do that if needed, and go on. Once I have run through the entire array and nothing has happend, I know I am done.

However, this is very time consuming as I am checking **a lot** of cells that don't even have sand on them, and going through an 1000x1000 array 95175 times (this is the time it takes to topple \$2^{20}\$ sand grains) takes a lot of time.

This is actually already an improved version, I tried a recursive one too, but that didn't work.

So, the complete code is:

```
Dim WDTH As Integer = 1000
Dim HGHT As Integer = 1000
Dim Array1(WDTH, HGHT) As Integer
Dim Done As Boolean
Dim Temp1 As Integer = 0
Dim Temp2 As Integer = 0
Dim BGW As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Not BGW.IsBusy Then            
        BGW.RunWorkerAsync()
        Button1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BGW_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BGW.DoWork
    For y As Integer = 0 To HGHT
        For x As Integer = 0 To WDTH
            Array1(x, y) = 0
        Next
    Next

    Array1(CInt(WDTH / 2), CInt(HGHTY / 2)) = 2 ^ 20

    Done = False
    Dim Iterationen As Integer = 0

    Do
        Done = True
        Iterationen += 1
        For y As Integer = 0 To HGHT
            For x As Integer = 0 To WDTH
                If Array1(x, y) >= 4 Then
                    Done = False
                    Temp1 = Array1(x, y) Mod 4
                    Temp2 = (Array1(x, y) - Temp1) / 4
                    Array1(x, y) = Temp1
                    Array1(x + 1, y) += Temp2
                    Array1(x - 1, y) += Temp2
                    Array1(x, y + 1) += Temp2
                    Array1(x, y - 1) += Temp2
                End If
            Next
        Next

        If BGW.CancellationPending Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Loop Until Done = True


    Dim BMP As New Bitmap(WDTH, HGHT)

    For y As Integer = 0 To HGHT - 1
        For x As Integer = 0 To WDTH - 1
            Select Case Array1(x, y)
                Case 0 : BMP.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White)
                Case 1 : BMP.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Green)
                Case 2 : BMP.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red)
                Case 3 : BMP.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Blue)
            End Select
        Next
    Next

    PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = BMP

    Beep()
End Sub

Private Sub BGW_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BGW.RunWorkerCompleted
    Button1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PictureBox1.Width = WDTH
    PictureBox1.Height = HGHT
End Sub
```

I tried reducing this as much as possible. The GUI contains a button named "Button1" and a picture box named "PictureBox1".

---

### This section contains a failed try. Please ignore it.

If you like to know, here is the recursive one:

### Calling the recursive function

```
ToppleSand(500, 500)
```

### The function itself

```
 Private Sub ToppleSand(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer)
    If Array1(x, y) >= 4 Then
        Temp1 = Array1(x, y)
        Array1(x, y) = Temp1 Mod 4
        Temp1 = (Temp1 - (Temp1 Mod 4)) / 4
        Array1(x + 1, y) += Temp1
        Array1(x - 1, y) += Temp1
        Array1(x, y + 1) += Temp1
        Array1(x, y - 1) += Temp1
        ToppleSand(x + 1, y)
        ToppleSand(x - 1, y)
        ToppleSand(x, y + 1)
        ToppleSand(x, y - 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

This got me a stackoverflow exeption, so I discarded this try.

Comment: "Can you show the whole method you are using ?" - So, you mean the entire programm? With graphics and GUI and everything?

Comment: Don't be confused by the ´ToppleSand()´ method. That was a failed try. I'll edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: Will review it tomorrow if no one reviewed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option Strict

Not setting `Option Strict` to `On` can lead to problems because it enables you to code without strictly typing. See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement

It can e.g lead to loss in precision or to a runtime exception.

---

### Naming and scope of variables

> ```
> Dim Array1(WDTH, HGHT) As Integer
> Dim Done As Boolean
> Dim Temp1 As Integer = 0
> Dim Temp2 As Integer = 0
> ```

These variables should be declared inside the `BGW_DoWork()` method. As a rule of thumb, one should declare variables as near to their usage as possible and should be scoped as thightly as possible.

While we are at the variables let's talk about naming.
Neither methods, nor parameters, variables, fields should be named using abbreviations. It makes your code harder to read if you first need to figure out in your head what e.g `HGHT` means. Writing code should be done in a way that enables the reader to grasp at first glance what the code is doing.

Based on the [.NET Naming Guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) variables/fields should be named using `camelCase` casing. Although VB isn't case sensitive you will do yourself a favour if you stick to the naming guidelines for each language you learn.

If a variable isn't meant to be changed by code you should make it a `const`, e.g your `WDTH` and `HGHT`.

---

### Performance

- By declaring `Array1` inside `BGW_DoWork()` you won't need to set the array items to `0`.
- Instead of `SetPixel()` you could use `Bitmap.LockBits()` like shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) but this will only save 1 second for a 1000x1000 bitmap.
- The calculation of the values when `Array1(x, y) >= 4` can be simplified by using integer division like so

  ```
  Done = False
  Temp2 = Array1(x, y) \ 4
  Array1(x, y) = Array1(x, y) Mod 4
  Array1(x + 1, y) += Temp2
  Array1(x - 1, y) += Temp2
  Array1(x, y + 1) += Temp2
  Array1(x, y - 1) += Temp2
  ```

  This saves around 20% of execution time which results in 984 seconds for 1000x1000.
- By using a 1d array the performace can be improved some more. Please note that the created image by the provided code looks good for 1000x1000 but not for a 100x100 (couldn't sort it out, will be glad if someone can point the problem).

  ```
  Private Function StabilizeGrains(piles() As Integer, gridWidth As Integer, gridHeight As Integer) As Boolean

      Dim allPilesAreStable As Boolean = True
      Dim width As Integer = 0
      For y As Integer = 0 To gridHeight - 1
          For x As Integer = 0 To gridWidth - 1

              Dim index As Integer = x + width
              Dim currentvalue As Integer = piles(index)

              If currentvalue > 3 Then

                  allPilesAreStable = False
                  Dim quarter As Integer = currentvalue \ 4

                  piles(index) = currentvalue Mod 4
                  If (x < gridWidth) Then
                      piles(index + 1) += quarter
                  End If
                  If (x > 0) Then
                      piles(index - 1) += quarter
                  End If
                  If (y < gridHeight - 1) Then
                      piles(index + gridWidth) += quarter
                  End If
                  If (y > 0) Then
                      piles(index - gridWidth) += quarter
                  End If

              End If

          Next
          width += WDTH
      Next
      Return allPilesAreStable
  End Function
  ```

  This method is called in the `BGW_DoWork()` method which looks like so

  ```
  Private Sub BGW_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BGW.DoWork

      Dim piles(WDTH * HGHT) As Integer

      Dim sandPlacingIndex As Integer = (WDTH * HGHT + WDTH) \ 2

      piles(sandPlacingIndex) = CInt(2 ^ 20)

      Dim Iterationen As Integer = 0

      Do
          Iterationen += 1

          If BGW.CancellationPending Then
              e.Cancel = True
              Exit Sub
          End If

      Loop Until StabilizeGrains(piles, WDTH, HGHT)

      PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = CreateBitmap(piles, WDTH, HGHT)

  End Sub
  ```

  The creation of the resulting image is extracted to its own method like so

  ```
  Private Function CreateBitmap(piles() As Integer, gridWidth As Integer, gridHeight As Integer) As Bitmap
      Dim bmp As New Bitmap(WDTH, HGHT)

      Dim width As Integer = 0
      For y As Integer = 0 To gridHeight - 1

          For x As Integer = 0 To gridWidth - 1
              Select Case piles(x + width)
                  Case 0 : bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White)
                  Case 1 : bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Green)
                  Case 2 : bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red)
                  Case 3 : bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Blue)
              End Select
          Next
          width += gridWidth
      Next
      Return bmp
  End Function
  ```

  These changes will lead to a processing time of 229 seconds.

  **Please note that measureing the times where done using poor man benchmarking aka StopWatch. So don't take them granted**

---

### Small Bug

If e.g `WDTH = 100` and `HGHT = 100` your code will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. If you want to prevent this you should add some `if` statements to check the values of `x` and `y`. This doesn't seem to be a problem with `WDTH = 1000` and `HGHT = 1000`.

Comment: According to the pattern the variable name `Done` is wrong, it should be `Dn` :-)

Comment: This might be the reason why the picture doesn't look good if the array is 100x100. You wrote: `Dim sandPlacingIndex As Integer = (WDTH * HGHT + WDTH) \ 2` but this doesn't quite center the sand pile. I guess this should be `Dim sandPlacingIndex As Integer = (WDTH * HGHT) \ 2`. Another idea: By letting the `x` and `y` range not from `0` but from `1` up to `gridHeight - 1` or `gridWidth - 1`, this should remove the out of range exeption and does not requiere the additional If-statements. Those were some ideas I had. But now I want to **thank you for your very detailed answer!** :D

Comment: Brain failed. The correct formula should be`Dim sandPlacingIndex As Integer = WDTH * (HGHT \ 2) + WDTH \ 2`

Comment: Thats exactly the same as I have written :-(

Comment: Weird. Hmmm... Do you mean by "doesn't look good" the fact that the picture is quite different from a cropped version of the 1000x1000 picture? If so: This normal and expected for an array too small.

Comment: If i use your code (slightly adjusted because of the `IndexOutOfRangeException`) the image looks different to mine.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. For some obscure reason I wasn't able to find yet, your code outputs the same picture as my code if my code has an even WDTH and HGHT and if your code has WDTH + 1 and HGHT + 1, expect your picture has one row and column more.

Comment: The picture becomes in fact identical if you modify the rendering of my code to display the full array (extend it by one row and column).